# Do Until statement in VB Excel not working properly

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, if-statement

The bottom row is the sum of the first two rows in the below image. (Ex: E11+E12=E13, F11+F12=F13 etc)

[image]

I am trying to make my code read the number of the bottom row cell, and then add to the top row cell until the bottom number cell exceeds a value of 10. Then it will go to the next cell in the row and do the same, until it gets to the end of the range. If the value is already at 10 of the bottom row cell, it will just skip over that one and move to the next cell.

Here is the code:

```vb
Sub For_Loop()

Dim k As Double

k = 0

For Each cell In Range ("E13:P13")
    If cell.Offset(2).Value < 10 Then

     Do Until cell.Offset(2).Value > 10 or k = 4000
     k = k + 1
     cell.Value = cell.Value + 1

     Loop
    
     Else
     cell.Value = cell.Value
     End If
Next


End Sub
```

Three issues are occurring:

First, the code is not stopping after the value exceeds 10. I added a counter (k) in order to stop the code, because it goes on forever if it is not there.

Second, the offset is not working. The code just adds to E13 instead of E11.

Third, the code is not going to the next cell after it is executed. Once the counter (k) hits 4000, it stops.

Please let me know of how I can fix this, or if additional information is needed.
Thank you!

Comment: Your sample data is all too similar to be able to figure out what the rules really are.  We can't read your code to do that either (since it doesn't do what you want)   `cell.Offset(2)` is two rows *below* `cell` - if you need to go "up" then you want `cell.Offset(-2)` (which would be the same column on row 11)

Answer (score 0):

### Increment Until Greater Than

[image]

**Math (Superior)**

```vb
Sub OverTheTreshold()
    
    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "E13:P13"
    Const ROW_OFFSET As Long = -2
    Const GT_TRESHOLD As Double = 10
    Const INCREMENT As Double = 1
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim cell As Range, cVal As Double
    
    For Each cell In ws.Range(SRC_RANGE).Cells
        cVal = cell.Value
        If cVal <= GT_TRESHOLD Then
            cVal = Int((GT_TRESHOLD - cVal) / INCREMENT) * INCREMENT + INCREMENT
            cell.Offset(ROW_OFFSET).Value = cell.Offset(ROW_OFFSET).Value + cVal
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

**Do Loop (Inferior)**

```vb
Sub OverTheTresholdLoop()
    
    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "E13:P13"
    Const ROW_OFFSET As Long = -2
    Const GT_TRESHOLD As Double = 10
    Const INCREMENT As Double = 1
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim cell As Range, cVal As Double, aVal As Long
    
    For Each cell In ws.Range(SRC_RANGE).Cells
        cVal = cell.Value
        Do While cVal + aVal <= GT_TRESHOLD
            aVal = aVal + INCREMENT
        Loop
        If aVal > 0 Then
            cell.Offset(ROW_OFFSET).Value = cell.Offset(ROW_OFFSET).Value + aVal
            aVal = 0
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```